# Sparse reading of 50gb file

Tags: c++

I have a 50gb file that I want to read.

There will be x instructions to read from the 50gb file. They will be in sequential order but the locations are unpredictable. Each instruction will read 1 byte.

The total reads account for < 0.0000001% of the total file size, probably around 100 bytes total.

Right now I am using seekg with offsets to do this but it is taking > 3 seconds sometimes.

Would memory mapping the file speed up the read in this case? Does it even make sense to memory map the file if I don't have 50gb of ram?

Is there something else I can do to speed this up?

Here is some code that takes around 2 seconds to run for me ( I adjusted it to make 300 reads to make it take longer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream in("E:/t.dat", ifstream::binary);
    in.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 1);
    set<long long> S;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
        S.insert((long long)(rand()%50000000)*1000ll);

    }

    long long offset = 0;
    in.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    int sum = 0;
    for(set<long long>::iterator it = S.begin(); it!=S.end(); it++){
        long long toseek = *it - offset;
        while(toseek > 2000000000){
            in.seekg(2000000000,ios::cur);
            toseek -= 2000000000;
            offset += 2000000000;
        }
        in.seekg(toseek,ios::cur);
        offset += toseek;
        char c;
        in.read(&c,1);
        offset++;
        sum += (int)c;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: interview question?  i used to ask something like that

Comment: @thang I really doubt that's an interview question. Files that large aren't used in many projects, thus the knowledge of handling them isn't something you would expect the majority to have. Also - even if it somehow _is_ an interview question - it still is on-topic and interesting.

Answer (score 4):

> Would memory mapping the file speed up the read in this case?

That's hard to answer without knowing more details about the file access patterns and the OS.  Your best bet would be to try it out and measure.  But for the non-memory mapping case, I'd recommend disabling buffering [`setvbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) on the file to avoid reading in any extra data (or alternatively, using the raw Unix file API of [`open(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)/[`lseek(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek)/[`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)/[`close(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close)).  You can also use [`posix_fadvise(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/posix_fadvise) to give hints to the OS about how to buffer the file pages -- in your case, you probably want to pass `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM` to tell it that you'll be accessing the file pages randomly, which *might* disable readahead behavior which would do unnecessary I/O.

> Does it even make sense to memory map the file if I don't have 50gb of ram?

Sure it does, as long as you have enough address space -- this won't work at all for a 32-bit process, but it will be fine in a 64-bit process.  The OS will allocate the virtual address space for the entire range of the file, but thanks to demand paging, it won't commit any physical memory to it until you actually read or write any given page.  If you happen to touch more pages than can fit in physical memory at once, then the pager will just page out the least recently used pages.

Comment: I tried using in.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 1) which gave no improvement, I will try out the memory map

Comment: another thing I forgot to mention is that this program will only be run once ever. Would memory mapping still be useful? ( I do not have a good grasp of what memory mapping is)

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I am using seekg with offsets to do this but it is taking > 3 seconds sometimes.

Post the code.

> Would memory mapping the file speed up the read in this case? Does it even make sense to memory map the file if I don't have 50gb of ram?

Probably not, and it probably wouldn't perform any better anyway, probably infinitely worse as you will cause swapping on a heroic scale.

> Is there something else I can do to speed this up?

Post the code.

Comment: What would cause the heroic swapping?  My understanding that only the mmap'd pages actually read by the process would be loaded in to RAM.